# Does a regular P-space always have clopen base?

Tags: general-topology

Just an the title explains, does a regular P-space always have clopen base? A P-space $X$ means that every $G_\delta$-subset of $X$ is open in $X$. Thanks ahead:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  For any $x \in X$ and any open neighbourhood $U_0$ of $x$ use regularity to construct a sequence $$U_0 \supseteq \overline{U}_1 \supseteq U_1 \supseteq \cdots \supseteq U_n \supseteq \overline{U}_{n+1} \supseteq U_{n+1} \supseteq \cdots \ni x.$$
Then $\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} U_n$ is G$_\delta$, and hence is an open neighbourhood of $x$ and $\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} U_n = \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \overline{U}_n$ is closed.  Therefore the clopen sets form a base for $X$.